# Maven Manifest file exclude full JAR path

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I was building a 'Maven module' project where there are 2 modules.

- Module A
- Module B

Module B is the one who uses Module A and when I run the Module B Main Class it runs perfect. But when I try to build a JAR from it, JAR includes invalid classpath jars in Manifest file.

**Module B POM**

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
         <configuration>
            <archive>
               <manifest>
                  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                  <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                  <mainClass>com.example.main.Main</mainClass>
               </manifest>
            </archive>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.10</version>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
               </configuration>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

Generated Manifest file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: Someone
Class-Path: lib/com/example/a/1.0.0/module-a-1.0.0.jar lib/com/1stl
 eg/jnativehook/2.0.2/jnativehook-2.0.2.jar lib/org/json/json/20160212
 /json-20160212.jar lib/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-client/2.22.2
 /jersey-client-2.22.2.jar lib/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0.1/javax
 .ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar lib/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-common/2.22.......
```

As I see there is additional paths to the 'Class-Path'. How do I modify this to include only the jar name?

I'm executing '**mvn clean install**'

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution adding following plugin will include the required JARs to the single JAR

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.4</version>
   <configuration>
      <archive>
         <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.example.main.Main</mainClass>
         </manifest>
      </archive>
      <descriptorRefs>
         <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>make-assembly</id>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to edit your pom.xml, you can make the same with `mvn package assembly:single`
 This command will also copy all of your dependencies into your .jar file.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that in any of your parent POMs the following has been configured `<classpathLayoutType>repository</classpathLayoutType>`. Remove it or override with `simple`.